# Fill URL fields with user input using PHP

Tags: php, html

i am looking for a simple quick solution to fill URL fields from a basic HTML menu (user choice) using PHP.

for example:
www.123.com/test.php?choice_1=**USER_Input**t&choice_2=**USER_Input**

so im looking to fill these 2 bold fields with the user choice and then request it. Its something i was asked to do at work and i don't have the privileges to access the database. I can only request a web page.

Comment: I am in the process of making the GUI using HTML i was just wondering if the request would work using these 2 fields as variables because i know that a URL must be within quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the data.

```
$url = "http://example.com/test.php?choice_1=" . urlencode($input1) . "&choice_2=" . urlencode($input2)
```

Comment: ok good i guess you answered my question about having a variable in a URL :)...will try it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick guide:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

URL will look something like this: `index.php?input1=VALUE&input2=VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Describe this HTML menu, is it a javascript one or a plain HTML menu with links in it? A javascript menu is more flexible and will let you pick multiple choices. Personally I would just use a HTML form and post it. Then you can do

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/test.php?choice1=' . $POST['one'] . '&choice2=' . $POST['two']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://123.com/test.php?';
$parts = array();
$request = array(
    'input_1' => $_POST['input_1'],
    'input_2' => $_POST['input_2'],
    'input_3' => $_POST['input_3'],
);
foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
    $parts[] = "{$key}={$value}";
}
$url .= implode('&', $parts);
```